# Duplicate Schema in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, schema

I am wanting to duplicate an existing schema with the table structure, but not any of the existing data. Essentially, we are separating two companies that currently share a single schema in the database, and they have the exact same data structure, but we want them in different schemas (for access control purposes).

It is possible to copy the entire table structure of one schema into a new schema without bringing over any of the data?

Comment: Script it out, search and replace the schema name then execute it?

Comment: I would also check out this similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080155/how-do-i-make-a-copy-of-a-table-within-sql-server-enterprise-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio)

- Right-click on the database
- Script Database as
- Create to
- File

Do a global search-and-replace in the resulting file, changing your schema name to their desired schema name.

I suggest going forward that you maintain change scripts to apply any needed changes to the DB as the application is further developed.  That way, you can just share the change scripts and each apply them when you are ready to upgrade the app version.